# tablesorter scrolling top when sorting is performed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

tablesorter scrolling to top while clicking on any column header for sorting action,
even though I placed scroller_upAfterSort: false in code, but its not working.

Please help to restore the scroller position before sorting.

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        showProcessing: true,
        widgets: ["zebra", "filter", "scroller"],
        widgetOptions: {
            scroller_height: 200,
            scroller_upAfterSort: false,
            scroller_jumpToHeader: false
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AlphaNumeric</th>
            <th>Numeric</th>
            <th>Animals</th>
            <th>Sites</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>abc 123</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Koala</td>
            <td>http://www.google.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>abc 1</td>
            <td>234</td>
            <td>Ox</td>
            <td>http://www.yahoo.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>zyx 12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Llama</td>
            <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>zyx 12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Llama</td>
            <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>zyx 12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Llama</td>
            <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>zyx 12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Llama</td>
            <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>zyx 12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Llama</td>
            <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>zyx 12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Llama</td>
            <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>zyx 12</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Llama</td>
            <td>http://www.nasa.gov/</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Demo**

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/venkatrjv/dve9448n/1/)

Comment: It looks like you discovered a bug, likely introduced in the last update. I [opened an issue for it](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/1297). I'll try to get it fixed soon.